# SCAD - Graduate Sound Design Program

Tags: scad, education, sound-design, training, job

Does anyone have any thoughts about the [Savannah College of Arts and Design Graduate Sound Design](https://www.scad.edu/academics/programs/sound-design) program. It looks like the program had a good, rounded curriculum which could help train me for future jobs in audio? Any thoughts?

pinman

[image: SCAD]
<sub>(source: [scad.edu](http://www.scad.edu/sound-design/images/quoteimage.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at SCAD's graduate program for sound design for a while. They have a great curriculum, and the school as a whole is very impressive. Few schools offer a masters program in sound design, and many schools will have a program more skewed toward music production than sound design. SCAD was certainly an exception to that. In my case, I ultimately went with a school that was a bit closer to where the jobs are, and where the instructors were still working on big-name projects, although David Stone is at the Savannah campus, and is pretty well recognized. Good luck with your decision.

Answer (score 1):

I graduated from the BFA program at SCAD in Sound Design about a year ago.  The program is great, you learn what you need to know and I was more prepared for LA then I could of ever imagined.  Now being in GA your not exposed to any of the industry except the few professors that have beefy resumes.  Although the school has an audio student organization which brings professionals in the Audio Post community to SCAD to lecture and talk about there experiences.  Its a great program with great facilities, not to mention SCAD also has music production classes if that's something your interested in.  It is quite expensive though so keep that in mind....

@josh-phippin

Comment: I just received goodnews that I got accepted to the Graduate Sound Design program and have received a scholarship as well. Do you know how many invididuals get accepted into the graduate program per year? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @pinman, I'm applying for the graduate program this year. Had you received a full scholarship? Can you tell me more about the financial aid process? Please write me to alansende@fibertel.com.ar. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Pinman, I would also like to know where you searched for scholarship assistance in getting a masters.  I continue to play with the idea of getting a Masters at American University, but it is pricey.

Comment: did you end up going @pinman?